# Python SOAP document handling

Tags: python, xml, soap, wsdl, suds

I've been trying to use [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki) for Python to call a SOAP WSDL. I just need to call the service programmatically and write the output XML document. However suds automatically parses this data into it's own pythonic data format. I've been looking through [the examples](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation) and [the documentation](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/), but I can't seem to find a way to return the XML document that the SOAP service gives me.

Is there an easy way to do this I'm overlooking? Is there an easier way to do this in Python than suds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this early stage in suds development, the easiest way to get to the raw XML content is not what one would expect.

The examples on the site show us with something like this:

```
client = Client(url)
result = client.service.Invoke(subm)
```

however, the result is a pre-parsed object that is great for access by Python, but not for XML document access. Fortunately the Client object still has the original SOAP message received stored.

```
result = client.last_received()
print result
```

Will give you the actual SOAP message received back.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at a library such as [soaplib](http://wiki.github.com/jkp/soaplib): its a really nice way to consume (and serve) SOAP webservices in Python.  The latest version has some code to dynamically generate Python bindings either dynamically (at runtime) or statically (run a script against some WSDL).

[disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the project! - I didn't write the bulk of it though]

Comment: 404 on link. Where did it move to?